# Oracle : Replace / Update using VALUES keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, pentaho

I know there are some questions similar to this, but as I am using Pentaho, I get one more constraint.
At the end of a transformation (= workflow), I want to insert data with the following code :
INSERT INTO my_table_name
(?)
VALUES
(?)

Both questions marks being variables with such forms :
(param1, param2, param3, etc.)
(value1, value2, value3, etc.)

The file where I extract the data contains violation on the primary key, so I want to insert or replace / update or maybe delete + insert.
And I can't change the input format.

I saw many answers about MERGE but it does not seem to achieve what I want to do.

Do you have any idea on how I could solve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Of course, explaining the minuses would be the least.

Comment: No, that's not possible. Column names can't be passed as parameters

Comment: MERGE really does sound like what you need to use, but as a_horse_with_no_name suggests, you'd have to have to know the column names you want to insert into.

Comment: As there are something like 15 parameters, and not always the sames depending on the lines read, I can't create a hard-coded statement.